# How to match pattern against multiple strings and store in data.frame in R

Tags: r, data.table, pattern-matching, string-matching

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 2),
          pattern = c("apple", "applejack", "bananas, sweet"))
dat2 <- data.frame(id2 = c(1174, 1231),
          description = c("apple is sweet", "bananass are not"),
          description2 = c("melon", "bananas, sweet yes"))

> dat1
  id1        pattern
1   1          apple
2   1      applejack
3   2 bananas, sweet
> dat2
   id2      description       description2
1 1174   apple is sweet              melon
2 1231 bananass are not bananas, sweet yes
```

I have two `data.frame`s, `dat1` and `dat2`. I would like to take each `pattern` in `dat1` and search for them in `dat2`'s `description` and `description2` using the regular expression, `\\b[pattern]\\b`.

Here is my attempt and the desired final output:

```
description_match <- description2_match <- vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(dat1)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(dat2)){
    search_pattern <- paste0("\\b", dat1$pattern[i], "\\b")
    description_match <- c(description_match, ifelse(grepl(search_pattern, dat2[j, "description"]), 1, 0))
    description2_match <- c(description2_match, ifelse(grepl(search_pattern, dat2[j, "description2"]), 1, 0))
  }
}
final_output <- data.frame(id1 = rep(dat1$id1, each = nrow(dat2)),
                           pattern = rep(dat1$pattern, each = nrow(dat2)),
                           id2 = rep(dat2$id2, length = nrow(dat1) * nrow(dat2)),
                           description_match = description_match,
                           description2_match = description2_match)

> final_output
  id1        pattern  id2 description_match description2_match
1   1          apple 1174                 1                  0
2   1          apple 1231                 0                  0
3   1      applejack 1174                 0                  0
4   1      applejack 1231                 0                  0
5   2 bananas, sweet 1174                 0                  0
6   2 bananas, sweet 1231                 0                  1
```

This approach is slow and not efficient if `dat1` and `dat2` have many rows. What's a quicker way to do this so that I can avoid a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `outer` and `Vectorize`d `grepl`.

```
r <- sapply(dat2[-1], \(x) +outer(dat1$pattern, x, Vectorize(grepl)))
cbind(dat1[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat1)), each=nrow(dat2)), ], id2=dat2$id2, r)
#     id1        pattern  id2 description description2
# 1     1          apple 1174           1            0
# 1.1   1          apple 1231           0            0
# 2     1      applejack 1174           0            0
# 2.1   1      applejack 1231           0            0
# 3     2 bananas, sweet 1174           0            0
# 3.1   2 bananas, sweet 1231           0            1
```

Comment: I got this error: `Error: unexpected input in "r <- sapply(dat2[-1], \"`

Comment: Use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` or update your R. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Is using `grepl` above equivalent to using `grepl("\\bapple\\b", "applesauce")` (which would return FALSE)?

Comment: You could also try `paste0("\\b", dat1$pattern, "\\b")` instead of `dat1$pattern` if you need the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution with:

- `tidyr::crossing` producing all combinations of `dat1` and `dat2`
- `stringr::str_detect` pairwise detecting the presence of a pattern in a string.

```r
library(tidyverse)

crossing(dat1, dat2) %>%
  mutate(across(contains('description'), ~ +str_detect(.x, sprintf('\\b%s\\b', pattern))))

# A tibble: 6 × 5
    id1 pattern          id2 description description2
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>       <int>        <int>
1     1 apple           1174           1            0
2     1 apple           1231           0            0
3     1 applejack       1174           0            0
4     1 applejack       1231           0            0
5     2 bananas, sweet  1174           0            0
6     2 bananas, sweet  1231           0            1
```

Comment: `str_detect("applesauce", pattern = "apple")` returns `TRUE`, but what I want to implement is `grepl("\\bapple\\b", "applesauce")` which returns `FALSE`. Is there an alternative to `str_detect`?

Comment: @Adrian you could also pass `regex` to `str_detect`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, but may be slower than @jay.sf's option

Your data frames:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 2),
                   pattern = c("apple", "applejack", "bananas, sweet"))
dat2 <- data.frame(id2 = c(1174, 1231),
                   description = c("apple is sweet", "bananass are not"),
                   description2 = c("melon", "bananas, sweet yes"))
```

Add a column with the pattern you'd like to use for matching:

```
dat1$pattern_grep = paste0("\\b", dat1$pattern, "\\b")
```

Perform a cartesian join: (i.e. join every row of dat2 to each row of dat1)

```
cj = merge(dat1, dat2, all = T, by = c())
```

Perform your `grepl` now:

```
cj$description_match <- mapply(grepl, cj$pattern_grep, cj$description)*1
cj$description2_match <- mapply(grepl, cj$pattern_grep, cj$description2)*1
```

- Think about the `mapply` as performing the `grepl` on each row of your data frame
- Multiplied by 1 to convert the boolean to 1/0

Keep relevant columns:

```
cj = cj[, c("id1", "pattern", "id2", "description_match", "description2_match")]

  id1        pattern  id2 description_match description2_match
1   1          apple 1174                 1                  0
2   1      applejack 1174                 0                  0
3   2 bananas, sweet 1174                 0                  0
4   1          apple 1231                 0                  0
5   1      applejack 1231                 0                  0
6   2 bananas, sweet 1231                 0                  1
```